# Grep for string only in checkout files

Tags: perforce

How do i search/ grep for a string only from the list of files that are checkout in
perforce.  I can get the list of files that are check out by me using this command : 
p4 opened -a | grep "username"..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it for you:

```
p4 opened -u <username> | cut -d "#" -f 1 | p4 -x - where | cut -d " " -f 3 | xargs grep <search string>
```

The piped commands do the following:

1. Get files opened by user
2. Get just the depot path for each file
3. Get p4 where output including the local file path in the 3rd column
4. Cut the output to get just the local file path
5. Grep for your string.

Note that adding the -u parameter to p4 opened is a more efficient way to get the files opened by a particular user than grepping the output of "p4 opened -a".